# 辞書からキーと値を順に取り出して処理する

Tags: python

月面での体重を計算して表示するプログラムを以下の作業を行って作成したいのですが月面での体重を計算し、表示するプログラムが分かりません。どのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

- 以下の名前と体重（kg）をキーと値のペアとして持つ辞書を作成し、変数に代入する

  ```
  'Alice': 44.5
  'Bob': 78.2
  'Carol': 50.0
  ```
- 辞書からキーと値を順に取り出し、以下の処理を行う
- 月面での体重を計算する
  月面での体重は地球にいるときの16.5パーセントです
- 名前と体重、月面での体重を表示する

実行結果は以下のとおりになります。
また、ここまで書けました。

```
Alice 44.5 7.3425
Bob 78.2 12.903
Carol 50.0 8.25
```

```
weights = {'Alice': 44.5, 'Bob': 78.2, 'Carol': 50.0}
for k, v in weights.items():
   print('%s 値:%s' % (k, v))
```

Comment: マルチポスト？同じ課題を出された人？ [以下の名前と体重（kg）をキーと値のペアとして...](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14256687324)

Comment: 確認したら一緒でびっくりしました。違うとは思うのですが

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問文を読むに、あと分からなかったのはここの部分ということですよね。

> 月面での体重を計算する
> 月面での体重は地球にいるときの16.5パーセントです

名前と体重は出力できているので、あとは月面での体重を計算するのみです。

```
for k, v in weights.items():
    print('%s 値:%s' % (k, v))
```

ここの `print` の前に、`v` を使って月面での体重を計算し、その結果を変数に代入しておいて、`print` で出力するのが分かりやすいでしょう。

```
for k, v in weights.items():
    weight_moon = # ここに計算式を入れる
    print('%s 値:%s' % (k, v)) # ここで新しく weight_moon も出力するようにする
```

※慣れてきたら `print` の中で計算しちゃうという手もあります。